# Recursive call to a function inside a class

Tags: python, function, class, oop, python-3.x

I'm working with classes in Python. I need to call a function recursively, but when I call it an error appears: `NameError: name 'dep_resolve' is not defined`

Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.edges = []
    def dep_resolve(node):
        print (node.name)
        for edge in node.edges:
            print(edge.name)
            dep_resolve(edge)
```

When at the last line a call `dep_resolve(edge)` the error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would pass the recursive call on to the next node, so call the method on that node:

```
def dep_resolve(node):
    print (node.name)
    for edge in node.edges:
        print(edge.name)
        edge.dep_resolve()
```

Note that you really want to use the name `self` instead; it is what every other Python developer uses:

```
def dep_resolve(self):
    print (self.name)
    for edge in self.edges:
        print(edge.name)
        edge.dep_resolve()
```

Comment: @Marijn Pieters if i use the second option and call ```self.dep_resolve(edge)``` it prints out ```TypeError: dep_resolve() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given```

Comment: @BioShock: see, that's where the use of `node` instead of `self` keeps tripping me up. :-P

Comment: Thank you! Last edit make it work perfectly! Do you know any good book to learn this?

Comment: @BioShock: sorry, I haven't read Python books in *ages* now, so I cannot recommend anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
       dep_resolve(edge)
```

Is a call to a method of the same class, so it needs a reference to the class instance ('self'):

```
       self.dep_resolve(edge)
```